# Disable Cash on Delivery for specific products

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.9

I am running Magento v1.9.0.1. I want to disable Cash on Delivery for specific products. I have installed COD extension from magento commerce.

I am new to Magento structure and no nothing to little about it. Tried some debugging on it but it is going up above my head.

Also, I have search every where over the internet but no one has ever provided the code for Magento v1.9.0.1.

Comment: can you share the link of the extension that u were installed??  Do u need any option for this in the admin side for disable COD for specific product??

Comment: I have installed COD extension by Mage Specialist. Here is the [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cash-on-delivery-3.html) to the extension. And yes I need option from admin side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom attribute with attribute code as `cod` and assign it to `General` of attribute sets.

Now as per you requirement change your methods.phtml (if there is no custom code included in this) as follows.

```
<?php
    $methods = $this->getMethods();
    $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
    </dt>
<?php else:
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
?>
    <dt>
    <?php 
    //cod verification starts
    $attr_cod = array();
    $cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        $attr_cod[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getCod();

    }
    if(in_array('1', $attr_cod) && $_code == 'cashondelivery') {continue; }
    //cod verification ends
?>
    <?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>

        <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
        <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
    </dt>
    <?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
    <dd>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;
    endif;
?>
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('additional'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('scripts'); ?>
    payment.init();
    <?php if (is_string($oneMethod)): ?>
    payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $oneMethod ?>');
        <?php endif; ?>
    //]]>
</script>
```

I have tested this and works fine.

Comment: Thanks man. It works for me. Could you please tell me how do I add extra COD fees in the order total?

Comment: for adding extra fee for COD option, you need to develop an extension. In short you need to setGrandTotal if the payment method is COD

Answer (score 1):

COD is already in magento you didn't need to install it.

There are two way

1. create a new config setting in which you can enter ids of products
   for which you didn't want COD option.
2. You can create product attribute too for checking COD option.

and check these ids (if you create config settings ) with the
    product id  or check for the product attribute on
    `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml`.
    And by simple if else conditions you can avoid COD option for these
    products.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please help me with the code. I have created the attribute for COD but I dont know how do I implement this in coding

Comment: I can't write code right now. i will provide you late night.
try to get cart session on that page. from cart session you will get product id then load that product on methods.phtml and check the attribute.
as per your website the payment method code is "p_method_phoenix_cashondelivery".  so put a if condition in which check for attribute, if attribute is there then put another check for not displaying COD.